# How often have Daleks appear on comedy television shows?

Tags: doctor-who, tv, dalek

Google put the video "Dalek Seven-2 on Spike Milligan's 'Q6'" in my search results, and I found it surprising to see a Dalek appear in a television sitcom (if indeed that's the right take on this).

**Question:** How often have Daleks appear on comedy television shows? Is this the only time, is there another example, or was it routine?

"bonus points" for ID of the second, naughty Dalek who'd destroyed its homework.

---

> Dalek Seven-2 appears on Spike Milligan's Q6 in December 1975. It would be the last time Dalek Two's skirt was seen on TV

Comment: another unusual Dalek sighting: [Location of this 1980's Dalek found in a scholarly article?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/168853/51174)

Comment: Also in a hilarious Red Nose Day special with Rowan Atkison 2009: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Do-wDPoC6GM. But if we are listing individual appearances instead of coming up with a single number, then this is a list question in disguise (I assume those are still frowned upon).

Comment: Also a (albeit rather DIY looking) Dalek in the video to "Doctoring the Tardis": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DsAVx0u9Cw4 (which personally I find pretty comedic). Maybe we can settle for "Routine".

Comment: And in a Quiz show alongside Jimmy Carr: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tT6rYTSCeKM

Comment: A few Daleks appeared on a Red Dwarf anniversary show: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cWA7rgCMGrA

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I looked for this a while ago, but misremembered it as a Peter Cook sketch

Comment: The reason the Daleks tend not to appear in comedy sketches is that their copyright isn't owned by the BBC but by the estate of their creator Terry Nation (thanks to a shrewd move by his agent at the time, who happens to be the mother-in-law of later Doctor Who showrunner Stephen Moffatt). The estate doesn't like the Daleks being made fun of so keep a tight rein on their use. Not sure how Spike Milligan got away with it - maybe it was unauthorised, which would have prompted Nation (still alive at the time) to clamp down even harder.

Comment: @GordonD interesting!

Answer (score 1):

There is this from [Vision On](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vision_On).

It was a show made for deaf children, so relied heavily on visual things, without  much dialogue. It was a frequent thing to show [Tony Hart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hart) drawing a picture, some of which then came to life.

It also starred Sylvester McCoy, years before he became the Doctor.

Answer (score 1):

There was a bit on Dave Allen At large where a familiar-looking baptismal font comes to life and chases the Vicar about the church yelling "Exterminate", and eventually disintegrating him and the lectern with the TARDIS sound effect being used.

Answer (score 1):

Daleks were at least the subject matter of a number of sketches in shows by Alexei Sayle, although they did not actually appear. Interestingly, Sayle actually appeared in the Sixth Doctor serial *Revelation of the Daleks*.

- A sketch in *Alexei Sayle's Stuff* centered around Margaret Thatcher using the TARDIS to go back in time and visit victims of the Black Plague. She then goes forward to visit an NHS hospital in the future, which looks exactly the same as the plague-ridden streets from the past. She is quoted as saying that "the Daleks do a wonderful job for which we should all be grateful and we should talk less about them exterminating people and more about the marvelous opportunities they bring to the electronics industry".
- Also, [this routine and sketch](https://youtu.be/mVfKvCuMGTg) from *Alexei Sayle's Merry-go-round* discusses Doctor Who and depicts various cheap-looking robots 'auditioning' for the position of Daleks.

As an aside, Sayle's series *The All New Alexei Sayle Show* had a recurring sketch called 'Drunk in Time' which was most likely a spoof of *Time Tunnel* but featured future Doctor Peter Capaldi as Sayle's time traveling companion.